# Need help printing a sorted file by days

Tags: c, file, sorting, printing

I'm writing a program to print days to an out file for students.
The low down is they will select from a list, and it hits my switch statemtnt below, where it calls my print statement. In the print statement it will have the sort function for the data structure. But i'm a little confused on how to write the function to sort it. I would like to sort by MWF and TR

Here is where the query statement happens, and below the query statement is the days sort.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
    #include "student.h"
    class_t classes[20];


    void queryUser(class_t classes[], int n){
    // This will prompt the user what they would like to do within the program
    // the idea here is to decide how each function needs to run
    char year;
    char user = 'a';
    char *time = " ";
    char *day = " ";
    char nl;
    // FILE* iptr = fopen("/public/csci112sp19/pgm1/classes.txt", "r");
    FILE* fptr = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    while(user != 'Q'){
        printf("What would you like to do?\n");
        printf("Print all classes: A\n");
        printf("Print all classes by day: B\n");
        printf("Print Classes by time: C\n");
        printf("Print all classes for student year: D \n");
        printf("Quit : Q\n");
        scanf("%c%c", &user, &nl);


        // there will be an switch case statement in this function
        // similar to if statements, if a case is called
        // the function will dictate what will print the information
        // stored in the selected array
        // put lower case in also
        printf("user is %c and n is %d\n", user, n);
        switch(user){
            case 'A':
                printAllClasses(classes, n,fptr);
                break;

            case 'B':
                printf("What days would you like to sort by MWF or TR?");
                scanf("%s", day);
                scanf("%c", &nl);
                printClassDay(classes, day , n, fptr);
                break;
            case 'C':
                printf("what time and what day");
                scanf("%s %s", time, day);
                scanf("%c", &nl);
                printClassTime(classes, day, time, n, fptr);
                //search array for day and time matching
                break;
            case 'D':
                printf("Please enter what year in school, Fresh: 1, Soph: 2, JR: 3, SR, 4\n");

                scanf("%c", &year);
                scanf("%c", &nl);
                yearMethod(classes, year, n, fptr);
                break;
            case 'Q':
                break;
            default:
                printf("Please use capital letters\n");
        }
    }
}
$


void sortbyclassdays(class_t classes[], int n, FILE* fptr){

    int i, j, doswap = 0;

    class_t temp;

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (j = i; j < n; ++j) {
            doswap = strcmp(classes[i].classDays, classes[j].classDays);
        }

        if (doswap > 0) {
            temp = classes[i];
            classes[i]= classes[j];
            classes[j] = temp;
        }
    }

    return;
}


void printClassDay(class_t classDays[], char* day, int n, FILE* fptr){
    //this method will print classes by days selected by user
    sortbyclassdays(classes, n, fptr);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        if(strcmp(day,"MWF")){
            printOneClass(classes[i], fptr);
        }
        else if(strcmp(day, "TR")){
            printOneClass(classes[i], fptr);
        }
    }
    return;
```

Comment: what are the contents of the home grown header file: `student.h`?

Comment: what's wrong with using the `qsort` standard library function?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding:

```
printf("What would you like to do?\n");
printf("Print all classes: A\n");
printf("Print all classes by day: B\n");
printf("Print Classes by time: C\n");
printf("Print all classes for student year: D \n");
printf("Quit : Q\n");
```

the function: `printf()` is an expensive consumer of CPU cycles.

The 'menu' will be difficult to read and understand.

Suggest:

```
printf("%s", 
       "\nWhat would you like to do?\n"
       "A: Print all classes:\n"
       "B: Print all classes by day:\n"
       "C: Print Classes by time:\n"
       "D: Print all classes for student year:\n"
       "Q: Quit\n");
```

or even better:

```
puts(  "\nWhat would you like to do?\n"
       "A: Print all classes:\n"
       "B: Print all classes by day:\n"
       "C: Print Classes by time:\n"
       "D: Print all classes for student year:\n"
       "Q: Quit\n");
```

OT: regarding:

```
scanf("%c%c", &user, &nl);
```

When calling any of the scanf() family of functions, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful. Note: the returned value is either EOF or the number of successful input format specifier conversions. In the current scenario suggest:

```
if( scanf("%c%c", &user, &nl) != 2) 
{ 
    // handle error 
}
```

regarding this kind of statement:

```
scanf("%c", &nl);
```

strongly suggest using:

```
int nl; 
while( (nl = getchar() ) != '\n' && nl != EOF );
```

regarding:

```
for (j = i; j < n; ++j) 
{ 
    doswap = strcmp(classes[i].classDays, classes[j].classDays); 
}
```

This will loop through all the 'classDays' then exit the loop So the next code block:, starting with:

```
if (doswap > 0)
```

will be only looking at the last entry in the array. So none of the other data will be sorted.

Your compiler 'may' let you get away with this:

```
 default:
     printf("Please use capital letters\n");
```

however, after the call to `printf()` should be:

```
     break;
```

regarding:

```
switch(user)
```

This will not work if the user enters a lower case letter.

Suggest:

```
switch( toupper(user) )
```

regarding:

```
char user = 'a';
```

the name `user` is not representative of its' contents.

Suggest something more meaningful, like:

```
selection
```

regarding:

```
void sortbyclassdays(class_t classes[], int n, FILE* fptr){
```

The function parameter: `FILE *fptr` is not used.  Suggest removing that function parameter and all references to it, in the rest of the code

regarding:

```
if(strcmp(day,"MWF")){
        printOneClass(classes[i], fptr);
    }
```

why skip records that do have: "MWF" in the 'day' field?

regarding:

```
else if(strcmp(day, "TR")){
        printOneClass(classes[i], fptr);
    }
```

Why skip records that have "TR" in the `day` field?

the posted code is missing a `main()` function and is missing the final `}` in the function: `printClassDay()`

Strongly suggest replacing the body of the function: `sortbyclassdays()`  with a sort algorithm that actually works.  Suggest: [bubble sort](https://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-bubble-sort)

the function: `printOneClass()` is missing from the posted code.

OT:  the functions that are declared to return `void` have a 'return` statement.  That statement is not needed

regarding statements like:

```
temp = classes[i];
classes[i]= classes[j];
classes[j] = temp;
```

It is very unlikely that these statements will actually move the whole `struct class_t`

Suggest:

```
memcpy( &temp, &classes[i], sizeof( class_t ) );
memcpy( &classes[i], &classes[j], sizeof( class_t ) );
memcpy( &classes[j], &temp, sizeof( class_t ) );
```